# Stay on same page after a form submit using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file

I am doing a post upload using ajax, but as I make a call to addPost.php it dose not return back and show result on same page it redirects to addPost.php and shows the result on that page.

As I tried alert in success method of ajax still it redirects to the another page.

Why is this happening so? For my other function like getCategories it returns the data well. What can be the problem in this?

I want to upload a file with this form,and data as well.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Post</title>
</head>
<body>

<form class="postForm" id="postForm" method="post" action="addPost.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please add the details below </legend>
        <p>
            <label for="title">Title (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
            <input id="title" name="title" minlength="2" type="text" required>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="desc">Description (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
            <input id="desc" name="desc" minlength="2" type="text" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="keywords">Keywords (eg:#facebook)(required, at least 2 characters)</label>
            <input id="keywords" name="keywords" minlength="2" type="text" required>
        </p>

        <select id="types" name="types" onchange="myFunction(this)">

            <option value="">Select type</option>

            <option value="2">Add Link</option>
            <option value="0">Upload Image</option>
            <option value="1">Upload Video</option>

        </select><br><br>

        <div id="link" style="display: none">

        <p>
            <label for="url">URL (required)</label>
            <input id="url" type="url" name="url" required>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="urlType">Select Url Type :(required)</label>
            <select name="urlType" id="urlType">
                <option value="">Select Url Type...</option>
        <!--        <option value="0">Server Image</option>
                <option value="1">Server Video</option>-->
                <option value="2">YouTube Video</option>
                <option value="3">Vimeo Video</option>
                <option value="4">Facebook Image</option>
                <option value="5">Facebook Video</option>
                <option value="6">Instagram Image</option>
                <option value="7">Instagram Video</option>
                <option value="-1">Other</option>
            </select>
        </p>

        </div>

        <div id="filediv" style="display: none">

            Select file to upload:
            <br><br>
            <input name="file1" type="file" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>

        </div>


        <p>
            <label for="postType"> Select Post Type :(required)</label>
            <select name="postType" id="postType">
                <option value="">Select Post Type...</option>
                <option value="0">Normal</option>
                <option value="1">Featured</option>
                <option value="2">Sponsored</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="category"> Select Category :(required)</label>
            <select name="category" id="category">
                <option value="">Select Category...</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="action_type" id="action_type_id"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="p_id"/>
<!--            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="$('#postForm').slideUp();">Cancel</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-success" onclick="userAction('add')">Add User</a>-->
           <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="result" id="result"></div>


</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.onerror = function(error, url, line) {
        controller.sendLog({acc:'error', data:'ERR:'+error+' URL:'+url+' L:'+line});
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        getCategories();
/*

        $("#postForm").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
*/

        $('#postForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength : 2
                },
                url: {
                    required: true
                },
                desc: {
                    required : true,
                    minlength : 2
                },
                keywords : {
                    required : true,
                    minlength : 2
                },
                urlType :
                    {
                        required : true
                    },
                postType :
                    {
                        required : true
                    },
                category :
                    {
                        required : true
                    },
                file1 :
                    {
                        required : true
                    }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {


                var url = document.getElementById('urlType').value;

                if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'facebook' && url == 6)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid facebook image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'facebook' && url == 7)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid facebook image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'facebook' && url == 3)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid facebook image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'facebook' && url == 2)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid facebook image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'instagram' && url == 3)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid instagram image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'instagram' && url == 2)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid instagram image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'instagram' && url == 4)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid instagram image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'instagram' && url == 5)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid instagram image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'vimeo' && url != 3)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid vimeo video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'youtube' && url != 2)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid youtube video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else {


                    userAction('add');

                  /*  var data = new FormData();
                    jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                        data.append('file-'+i, file);
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'addPost.php',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        data: $('#postForm').serialize(),
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            //alert(report);
                            $(".result").html(report);
                            $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
                        }
                    });
*/

                    /*             jQuery.ajax({
                                     url: 'addPost.php',
                                    // data: data,
                                     data: $('#postForm').serialize(),
                                     cache: false,
                                     contentType: false,
                                     processData: false,
                                     encctype: "multipart/form-data",
                                     type: 'POST',
                                     success: function(report){
                                         alert(report);
                                        // $(".result").html(report);
                                         $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
                                     }
                                 });*/
                 //   e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });

    });

    function getCategories() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'getCategories.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {

                $('#category').html(result);
            }
        });

    }


    function userAction(type,id){

    /*    var statusArr = {add:"added",edit:"updated",delete:"deleted"};

*/
        var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

        // Create an FormData object
        var data = new FormData(form);

        if (type == 'add') {

            $('#action_type_id').val(type);
            $('#p_id').val(id);
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addPost.php',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
         //   data : data,
         //   data: $(this).serialize(),
            data: $('#postForm').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success:function(report){
                // replace data to report

            $(".result").html(report);
            $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
            }
        });
     //   e.preventDefault();

/*
    $("form#data").submit(function(){

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'addPost.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                $(".result").html(report);
                $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });*/

      /*  var data = new FormData();
        jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
            data.append('file-'+i, file);
        });


        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'addPost.php',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(report){
                $(".result").html(report);
                $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
            }
        });*/

    }

    function myFunction(obj) {

        var type = obj.value;
        var x = document.getElementById('link');
        var y = document.getElementById('filediv');


        if(type == "2")
        {
            x.style.display = 'block';
            y.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            x.style.display = 'none';
            y.style.display = 'block';
        }

    }

    function validate_url(url)
    {
        if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook.com\/.*/i.test(url))
            return 'facebook';

        if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook.com\/.*/i.test(url))
            return 'facebook';

        if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)instagram.com\/.*/i.test(url))
            return 'instagram';

        if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)vimeo.com\/.*/i.test(url))
            return 'vimeo';

        if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)youtube.com\/.*/i.test(url))
            return 'youtube';

        return 'unknown';
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT :

```
   else {
               // userAction('add');

                var data = new FormData();
                jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                    data.append('file-'+i, file);
                });
                e.preventDefault();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'addPost.php',
                   // data: data,
                    data: $('#postForm').serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    encctype: "multipart/form-data",
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(report){
                        alert(report);
                       // $(".result").html(report);
                        $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
                    }
                });
             //   e.preventDefault();
            }
```

Tried like this still it redirects to the next page.

addPost.php

```
    <?php

include 'Database.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('post_max_size', '1.8G');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1.8G');


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

         $database = new Database(Constants::DBHOST, Constants::DBUSER, Constants::DBPASS, Constants::DBNAME);
        $dbConnection = $database->getDB();
        $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("insert into keywords(keyword) 
                                    values(?)");
        $stmt->execute(array($_POST['keywords']));

        $file_result = "";

        if(strcmp($_POST['types'],"2") == 0)
        {

            //insert data into posts table
            $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("insert into posts(category_id,title,url,url_type,description,keywords,post_type) 
                                    values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->execute(array($_POST['category'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['url'], $_POST['urlType'], $_POST['desc'], $_POST['keywords'],$_POST['postType']));

            $count = $stmt->rowCount();

            if ($count > 0) {

                echo "Post submitted.";
            } else {

                echo "Could not submit post.";
            }


        }
      else {

                if (isset($_FILES["file1"]["name"])) {

                    $file_result = "";

                    if ($_FILES["file1"]["error"] > 0) {
                        $file_result .= "No file uploaded or invalid file.";
                        $file_result .= "Error code : " . $_FILES["file1"]["error"] . "<br>";
                    } else {

                        if (strcmp($_POST['types'], "0") == 0) {
                          //  $target_dir = "./agtvapp/images/";
                            $target_dir = "images/";
                        } else {
                           // $target_dir = "./agtvapp/videos/";
                            $target_dir = "videos/";
                        }

                        $newfilename = preg_replace('/\s+/', '',
                            $_FILES["file1"]["name"]);
                        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($newfilename);

                     /*   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file1"]["name"]);*/

                        $file_result .=
                            "Upload " . $_FILES["file1"]["name"] . "<br>" .
                            "type " . $_FILES["file1"]["type"] . "<br>" .
                            "temp file " . $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

                        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

                            $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("insert into posts(category_id,title,url,url_type,description,keywords,post_type) 
                                    values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                            $stmt->execute(array($_POST['category'], $_POST['title'], $newfilename, $_POST['types'], $_POST['desc'], $_POST['keywords'], $_POST['postType']));

                            $count = $stmt->rowCount();

                            if ($count > 0) {

                                echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['file1']['name']) . " has been uploaded, and post submitted.";

                            } else {

                                echo "Could not submit post.";
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
                else{

                    echo 'empty file';
                }
            }

}
?>
```

Here I dont understand, if I write       data: $('#postForm').serialize(), to send the form in userAction function for ajax then I get the $_FILES array as empty, but the same code if I am doing directly in else part of validate function then the files array is not empty the file gets uploaded successfully but it redirects to next page. And From userAction function it dose not redirect to next page but I get $_FILES array empty so  can not upload the file.

Please, can anyone help with this? I am a beginner in web development so not getting hoe to do this. Thank you.

Comment: You need to move the preventDefault call to the start of the function. and it needs to reference the form object in the DOM.

Comment: have you tried a `preventDefault` at the beginning so that jQuery does not process the form to the mentionned action URL ?

Comment: $("#postForm").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });  I tried this in document.ready function after getCategories() is called. but then it dose not submit for at all, addPost.php dose not get called. @OldPadawan

Comment: $("#postForm").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }); I tried this in document.ready function after getCategories() is called. but then it dose not submit for at all, addPost.php dose not get called. @SloanThrasher

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post code in the comments.

Comment: move up your preventdefault function

Comment: The preventDefault should be in the same function as the ajax call, but just before it. Like just before ```var url = document.getElementById('urlType').value;```

Comment: I see you edit the question, but you didn't add the PHP code that is doing the query using the $_POST data. If you want an answer, you have to provide what we're asking for.

Comment: Please check edited question I tried both the ways before url and as did in edited question still it redirects to the another form. @SloanThrasher

Comment: The preventDefault call needs to be the first thing in the on submit handler of the form.

Comment: I tried that too. but not working. @SloanThrasher

Comment: Since I can't see enough of your code to find the error, you're on your own. Good luck.

Comment: I provided the addPost file and all the code. @SloanThrasher

Comment: You've asked about two things. The problem with the page submitting is not in the addPost.php, but in the page with the Javascript that calls ajax.

Comment: yes so I had only provided the form has issue in but u asked for addPost.php so I provided that. And the problem is only one that form gets redirect did not ask for two things. @SloanThrasher

Comment: try to with this <form onsubmit="return false;">

Comment: addPost.php dose not get called if done this and form dose not get submit. @Javed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this file in seperate

index.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Post</title>
</head>
<body>

<form class="postForm" id="postForm" method="post" action="addPost.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please add the details below </legend>
        <p>
            <label for="title">Title (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
            <input id="title" name="title" minlength="2" type="text" required>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="desc">Description (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
            <input id="desc" name="desc" minlength="2" type="text" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="keywords">Keywords (eg:#facebook)(required, at least 2 characters)</label>
            <input id="keywords" name="keywords" minlength="2" type="text" required>
        </p>

        <select id="types" name="types" onchange="myFunction(this)">

            <option value="">Select type</option>

            <option value="2">Add Link</option>
            <option value="0">Upload Image</option>
            <option value="1">Upload Video</option>

        </select><br><br>

        <div id="link" style="display: none">

        <p>
            <label for="url">URL (required)</label>
            <input id="url" type="url" name="url" required>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="urlType">Select Url Type :(required)</label>
            <select name="urlType" id="urlType">
                <option value="">Select Url Type...</option>
        <!--        <option value="0">Server Image</option>
                <option value="1">Server Video</option>-->
                <option value="2">YouTube Video</option>
                <option value="3">Vimeo Video</option>
                <option value="4">Facebook Image</option>
                <option value="5">Facebook Video</option>
                <option value="6">Instagram Image</option>
                <option value="7">Instagram Video</option>
                <option value="-1">Other</option>
            </select>
        </p>

        </div>

        <div id="filediv" style="display: none">

            Select file to upload:
            <br><br>
            <input name="file1" type="file" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>

        </div>


        <p>
            <label for="postType"> Select Post Type :(required)</label>
            <select name="postType" id="postType">
                <option value="">Select Post Type...</option>
                <option value="0">Normal</option>
                <option value="1">Featured</option>
                <option value="2">Sponsored</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="category"> Select Category :(required)</label>
            <select name="category" id="category">
                <option value="s">Select Category...</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="action_type" id="action_type_id"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="p_id"/>
<!--            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="$('#postForm').slideUp();">Cancel</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-success" onclick="userAction('add')">Add User</a>-->
           <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="result" id="result"></div>


</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.onerror = function(error, url, line) {
        controller.sendLog({acc:'error', data:'ERR:'+error+' URL:'+url+' L:'+line});
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        getCategories();
/*

        $("#postForm").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
*/

        $('#postForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength : 2
                },
                url: {
                    required: true
                },
                desc: {
                    required : true,
                    minlength : 2
                },
                keywords : {
                    required : true,
                    minlength : 2
                },
                urlType :
                    {
                        required : true
                    },
                postType :
                    {
                        required : true
                    },
                category :
                    {
                        required : true
                    },
                file1 :
                    {
                        required : true
                    }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {


                var url = document.getElementById('urlType').value;

                if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'facebook' && url == 6)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid facebook image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'facebook' && url == 7)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid facebook image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'facebook' && url == 3)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid facebook image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'facebook' && url == 2)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid facebook image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'instagram' && url == 3)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid instagram image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'instagram' && url == 2)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid instagram image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'instagram' && url == 4)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid instagram image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'instagram' && url == 5)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid instagram image,video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'vimeo' && url != 3)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid vimeo video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'youtube' && url != 2)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid youtube video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else {


                    userAction('add');

                  /*  var data = new FormData();
                    jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                        data.append('file-'+i, file);
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'addPost.php',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        data: $('#postForm').serialize(),
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            //alert(report);
                            $(".result").html(report);
                            $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
                        }
                    });
*/

                    /*             jQuery.ajax({
                                     url: 'addPost.php',
                                    // data: data,
                                     data: $('#postForm').serialize(),
                                     cache: false,
                                     contentType: false,
                                     processData: false,
                                     encctype: "multipart/form-data",
                                     type: 'POST',
                                     success: function(report){
                                         alert(report);
                                        // $(".result").html(report);
                                         $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
                                     }
                                 });*/
                 //   e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });

    });

    function getCategories() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'getCategories.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {

                $('#category').html(result);
            }
        });

    }


    function userAction(type,id){

    /*    var statusArr = {add:"added",edit:"updated",delete:"deleted"};

*/


        var form = $('#postForm')[0];

        // Create an FormData object
        var data = new FormData(form);

        if (type == 'add') {

            $('#action_type_id').val(type);
            $('#p_id').val(id);
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'add.php',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data : data,
            success:function(report){
                // replace data to report

            $(".result").html(report);
            $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
            }
        });
     //   e.preventDefault();

/*
    $("form#data").submit(function(){

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'addPost.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                $(".result").html(report);
                $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });*/

      /*  var data = new FormData();
        jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
            data.append('file-'+i, file);
        });


        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'addPost.php',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(report){
                $(".result").html(report);
                $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
            }
        });*/

    }

    function myFunction(obj) {

        var type = obj.value;
        var x = document.getElementById('link');
        var y = document.getElementById('filediv');


        if(type == "2")
        {
            x.style.display = 'block';
            y.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            x.style.display = 'none';
            y.style.display = 'block';
        }

    }

    function validate_url(url)
    {
        if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook.com\/.*/i.test(url))
            return 'facebook';

        if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook.com\/.*/i.test(url))
            return 'facebook';

        if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)instagram.com\/.*/i.test(url))
            return 'instagram';

        if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)vimeo.com\/.*/i.test(url))
            return 'vimeo';

        if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)youtube.com\/.*/i.test(url))
            return 'youtube';

        return 'unknown';
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

add.php

```
<?php

echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES); 
exit();


 ?>
```

Comment: in order to use formdata with jquery you have to set the correct options 
   
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

Comment: not working, nothing happens on click of submit. are you send data twice? still works? @Nobita

Comment: it just clears the form onClick of submit, I have added print $files in addPost.php its not printing that too, post for a link works fine but not for file upload. @Nobita

Comment: w8 I post my work out you can check it that works fine

Comment: the problem is with your ajax part to use formdata with jquery you have to set the options processData: false, contentType: false

Comment: Happy coding :)